# String Not allowed in android studio???/

Tags: android, android-studio

I keep receiving a string types not allowed in Android studio for these two types of lines below and i was wondering How I should go about resolving them.

app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="num_of_laborers_textView7"

and

app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="num_of_laborers_textView7"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values of those attributes need to be widget IDs, of other widgets that are children of the `ConstraintLayout`. If `num_of_laborers_textView7` is a widget ID, then the syntax should be `@id/num_of_laborers_textView7`.

Comment: Thank You so much the error went away but now all my stuff is in a corner.I think I can figure it out though. Again I appreciate the advice it worked wonders.